# Live reload react app working with docker-compose

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I have two services: front (product-list) and backend (server-api).

I've created a docker-compose file and it works fine:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  server-api:
    build: ./server-api
    ports: 
      - "8080:8080"
  product-list:
    build: ./product-list
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - server-api
```

But I have a problem: the app doesnt reload after a change.

I have read about this, and a lot of people says that `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"` should works.

It doesnt for me.

I would like to know if is a volume problem (I dont have very clear how they work right now or what volume should I create), or if maybe I should install something to watch the files.

This is the Dockerfile that I have in my frontend app:

```
FROM node:14-alpine AS development

ENV NODE_ENV development

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And right now I just use `docker-compose up` to launch the app.

I just need to know about what happend with my react app and why it doesnt reload, backend service (server-api) works fine and I dont need hot reload in that app.

Any help is thankful.

Comment: Do you actually need Docker here?  Particularly for developing a front-end application, you might find it easier to just use Node directly, without trying to work around Docker's isolation features.

Comment: Is just to learn.

Answer (score 0):

For the changes to get into container, you need to mount the project as volume. In the current configuration, changes to the project will fall into container only after rebuilding the image.

As example:

```yaml
  product-list:
    build: ./product-list
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - server-api
    volumes:
      - ".:/app"
```